# supervisor cannot stop process of gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I run my django project by gunicorn and supervisor. but I am running into a strange problem, `supervisorctl stop <myproject>`  can NOT stop gunicron. when I ps the process, I found the process still there.

gunicorn settings:

```
$PROJECT_DIR/.env/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE} \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE} \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--worker-class $WORKER_CLASS \
--user=$USER \
--group=$GROUP \
--log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
--bind=$SERVER_NAME:$PORT
```

supervisor settings:

```
[program:myproject]
user=www
command=/var/www/apps/myproject/scripts/bin/gunicorn.sh
stopsignal=KILL
stopasgroup=true
directory=/var/www/apps/myproject
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/gunicorn.log
```

Comment: why don't you just kill it?

Comment: What is the output when you call `supervisorctl stop myproject` and `supervisorctl status`? Is it possible that a different gunicorn process has been started without using supervisor?

Comment: if stop the myproject, the status is STOPPED. I personally think it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simpler supervisor config, it's probably happening because of autostart - reloading supervisor settings will start all listed programs with autostart.

Answer (score 0):

I change the way of configuration like this way:

```
exec $PROJECT_DIR/.env/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=${DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE} \
--name $NAME \
--workers $NUM_WORKERS \
--worker-class $WORKER_CLASS \
--user=$USER \
--group=$GROUP \
--log-level=$LOG_LEVEL \
--bind=$SERVER_NAME:$PORT
```

`exec` to call gunicorn and `${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application`, then it works, to be honest, I have no idea why.

Anyway, thanks all. ^_^